# How to run a fixed command when every session starts in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I use Hibernate to access a SQL Server database for developing our API. The database has some columns are encrypted. To be able to decrypt these encrypted columns, I need to run the following statement before select/insert/update statements:

`OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_MyApp DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_MyApp`

Also I need to run the following statement before the session is closed:

`CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_MyApp`

Is there a way to run the statements above whenever a session is open or close? I mean just write some code in one place. When a session is open, it runs the first statement. When a session is close, it runs the second statement. I tried to use EventListener, but I couldn't run these statements because of ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is best solved at the datasource level. Not sure what your environment looks like, but if you use [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) for example, you can configure the `connectionInitSql` which will be executed after a connection is created. Other datasource implementation probably provide a similar way to do this.

Comment: Yes, your solution works. Thanks. We are using c3p0 for connection pool and it also supports initSql. I tested and it worked, ie, whenever a connection is checked out, it runs the specified sql statement. Also I customized AbstractConnectionCustomizer to run the specified sql statement when a connection is checked in to the pool.